# removing empty rows in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a data set like blow:

```
1,abc,10000
,zxcv,2000
, , ,
4,xyz,50000
```

I want output like:

```
1,abc,10000 
zxcv,2000
4,xyz,50000
```

How can I achieve this task?
I.e I want to remove the empty rows and `null` values.

Answer (score -1):

Try [Filter Operator](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#FILTER) :

```
A = LOAD 'your_data' USING PigStorage() AS (your fields);

B = FILTER A BY your_fields IS NOT NULL;
```